# Geocoding using herepy package behind a proxy

Tags: python, geolocation, here-api, herepy

I'm tryng to retrieve the geocoordinates of a given address using the **herepy** package on Python. As I'm working behind a network proxy,  I've initialized the proxy environment variable with the proxy.

```
import os
import herepy 

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy

geocoderApi = herepy.GeocoderApi(HERE_AppID, HERE_AppCode)
response = geocoderApi.free_form('200 S Mathilda Sunnyvale CA')
```

However, I'm getting the SSLError when I run the codes. Does anyone has any idea of what went wrong?

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='geocoder.cit.api.here.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200+S+Mathilda+Sunnyvale+CA&app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxxxxxxxCaused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Answer (score 0):

This `herepy` package is not provided and supported by HERE. We provide standard REST APIs in addition to our JavaScript, Android and IOS SDKs.
Please use  urllib(3) and other standard requests libraries in Python that provides means to handle proxies.